# Hamcrest Matcher for an item in an array of a certain class

Tags: java, hamcrest

I have a List<Object> and want to verify in jUnit that the list has an object of a certain type.  I tried this:

```
assertThat(myList,hasItem(isA(ExpectedClass.class)));
```

But, I get this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: a collection containing null
     but: 
    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:20)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:865)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:832)
```

Could someone tell me how to build the appropriate matcher?

Comment: Can you show the static imports you're using for `hasItem` and `isA`, to confirm that they're both Hamcrest?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you've used junit's assertThat instead of hamcrest's.

```
import org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;
```

works fine.